# Is there an inverse power series?

Tags: power-series, laurent-series

Is there power series that has this kind of form? How would you go about finding the coefficients $a_k$?
$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_k}{x^k}
$$
For e.g. what would be $\sin(x)$ in terms of this series?

Comment: You've tagged the answer, have you not? This is the negative-coefficient part of a Laurent series and therefore you should know that the positive part cannot be omitted.

Comment: Expressing $\sin x$ in this form is problematic because of the behaviour near $x=0$.

Comment: $\sin$ is not analytic at $\infty$ so it can't be written this way.

Comment: Read about [Laurent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_series)

Comment: Consider the function $g(x)=f(\frac{1}{x})$. If you can write $g(x)$ as a power series then you'll be set. This will work for some but not all functions.